# How to make some checkboxes checked, based on an array of checked values React JS, Inertia JS

Tags: reactjs, inertiajs

I am working on a React JS with Inertia JS combined application. I'm in the progress to finish my edit feature. so I need to make some checkboxes to be checked default based on a set of values in an array.

I loop the checkbox to let the user choose the list of permissions and some of them should be already checked based on the data from the array.

I'm confused to fix the problem, sometimes I success to checked them but all of the checkbox checked also can't uncheck the checkbox.

this is my code

```
export default function EditPermission (props){
const {role} = usePage().props
const { data, setData, put, processing, errors, reset } = useForm({
    name: role.name || '',
    permissions: [] // store the permissions data on role

})

const mapPermissionsOnRole = () => {
    for(let i=0; i < role.permissions.length; i++){
       data.permissions.push(role.permissions[i]['name'])
    }
} //map the already exist permissions and push to data.permissions

const handleChecked = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.name;
    if (e.target.checked) {
        setData("permissions", [...data.permissions, value]);

    } else {
        setData(
            "permissionss",
            data.permissions.filter((item) => {
                return item !== value
            })
        );
    }
};

const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    put(route('role.update',permission.id));
};



return (
    <AuthenticatedLayout auth={props.auth} errors={props.errors}>
    <div className="w-full lg:max-w-6xl mt-6 px-6 py-4 bg-white shadow-md overflow-hidden sm:rounded-lg">        

        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <div>
                    {props.permissions && props.permissions.length > 0 ? role.permissions.map((permissions, i) => {
                        return(
                            <div>
                                <Checkbox checked={props.permissions[i].name.includes(data.permissions)} name={permissions.name} value={data.permissions} handleChange={handleChecked} />{permissions.name}
                            </div>
                        )
                            
                            
                        }):<p>Permissions Coming Soon!</p>
                    }

                <PrimaryButton className="ml-4" processing={processing}>
                    Update
                </PrimaryButton>
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>

    </AuthenticatedLayout>
    
)
```

}

Comment: `checked={props.permissions[i].name.includes(data.permissions)}` ||
two things for above code:

1- is `data.permissions` an array?, if so then is `props.permissions[i].name` also an array?
2- we are using data from `props` to update the `checked` prop (shouldn't we use `data` from `useForm` here)?

Comment: ok , quest 1 , data.permissions is an array which contain only permissions on role specific role and props.permissions[i].name i use this for show all the permissions i have , question 2 i use data from props only for show all the permissions data @ShyamMittal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call const `mapPermissionsOnRole`.
try using the `useEffect` to call the data and push it to the array of `data.permissions`.

A quick tip is to use the id better than the name of the permission for comparison or use a new attribute on the database that the data is `is_checked` or not.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
        let ignore = false;
        
        if (!ignore)  mapPermissionsOnRole()
        return () => { ignore = true; }
        },[]
    ); do you mean this ?

Comment: so better to compare the id from the database?

Comment: I mean that `mapPermissionsOnRole` is set but not called on the function, what is the output that you get from this overall on the page?

Comment: you can use the `id` not the `name` as an index to compare if it there or not this is better than the `name` because the name is not a unique attribute.